# fgets combined with sscanf

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, stream

Today I've looked over some C code that was parsing data from a text file
and I've stumbled upon these lines

```
fgets(line,MAX,fp);
if(line[strlen(line)-1]=='\n'){
    line[strlen(line)-1]='\0');
}else{
    printf("Error on line length\n");
    exit(1);
}
sscanf((line,"%s",records->bday));
```

with record being a structure

```
typedef struct {
    char bday[11];
}record;
```

So my question here regards the fgets-sscanf combination to create a type/length safe stream reader:

- Is there any other way to work this out beside having to combine these two readers?
- What about the `\n` checking-removing sequence?

Comment: You have a bug there. The `if` condition should have `==`, not `=`. And the `else` will incorrectly give an error if the last line in the file didn't have a newline.

Comment: `if ((fscanf(fp, "%10s%c", records->bday, &dummy) != 2) || (dummy != '\n')) /* deal with error */;`

Comment: @interjay thx for pointing it out,it was a typing error and got it corrected :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight in this case MAX is 60 as the file should contain only birth-day dates names and id-numbers(with a lenght of 6), the fgets-sscanf is only used for the birth day dates and the id's while the names are treated with a different approach (fgets trimmed '\n' and copied in a pointer of chars (the pointer is first malloced with sizeof(buffer)) therefore i've left out htese details because were'nt too important i suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of `fgets()` with `sscanf()` is usually good.  However, you should probably be using:

```
if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
{
    ...
}
```

This checks for I/O errors and EOF.  It also assumes that the definition of the array is visible (otherwise `sizeof` gives you the size of a pointer, not of the array).  If the array is not in scope, you should probably pass the size of the array to the function containing this code.  All that said, there are worse sins than using `MAX` in place of `sizeof(line)`.

You have not checked for a zero-length birthday string; you will probably end up doing quite a lot of validation on the string that is entered, though (dates are fickle and hard to process).

Given that MAX is 60, but `sizeof(records->bday) == 11`, you need to protect yourself from buffer overflows in the `sscanf()`.  One way to do that is:

```
if (sscanf(line, "%10s", records->bday) != 1)
    ...handle error...
```

Note that the `10` is `sizeof(records->bday) - 1`, but you can't provide the length as an argument to `sscanf()`; it has to appear in the format string literally.  Here, you can probably live with the odd sizing, but if you were dealing with more generic code, you'd probably think about:

```
sprintf(format, "%%%zus", sizeof(records->bday) - 1);
```

The first `%%` maps to `%`; the `%zu` formats the size (`z` is C99 for `size_t`); the `s` is for the string conversion when the format is used.

Or you could consider using `strcpy()` or `memcpy()` or `memmove()` to copy the right subsection of the input string to the structure - but note that `%10s` skips leading blanks which `strcpy()` et al will not.  You have to know how long the string is before you do the copying, of course, and make sure the string is null terminated.